# Good approach for using C++ dll for Testing

Tags: c++, dll, wsdl

Testing team got a C++ dll from the DEV team. The methods in that dll has to be tested by passing input parameters. The expected output is already available in SQL DB.

What is the better way to test that dll and verify&validate the results ?

Few suggested to use WebService using WSDL(from dll). Once that is done, then compare the  results from the webservice with existing data in SQL.

Is this a better approach or any simple approach ?

Please help.

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you got the DLL:

1. In case you have the DLL header file and .LIB create a new project and LINK to the DLL
2. if you don't have the LIB and the header: Load the library using appropriate Windows API

The second approach uses LoadLibraryEx/GetProcAddress - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and assumes you have plain methods in your DLL ... If this is not the case you might need to fall back to 1.

then

1. Write code to execute the methods in the DLL
2. Write code to load the expected output from the SQL DB (whatever that might be)
3. Write code to compare the output of those two...

Basically these are the steps, of course you can refine.